# c#, getting pixel information from Bitmap image not giving required result

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, bitmap

I want to get any image, convert it to a bitmap, resize it to (1024,16) then
get the RGB value of each pixel.

This is my function to resize

```
public Bitmap Resize(bitmap image1)
{
    Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(16, 1024);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(image2);
    gr.DrawImage(image1,0,0,image2.Height,image2.Width);
    return image2;
}
```

Then this is my function to get the RGB value of each pixel and write it to a text file

```
for (int y = 0; y < image2.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image2.Width; x++)
    {         
        Color pixelcolor = image2.GetPixel(x,y);
        byte weR = pixelcolor.R;
        byte weG = pixelcolor.G;
        byte weB = pixelcolor.B;

        sR.WriteLine(weR.ToString());
        sR.WriteLine(weG.ToString());
        sR.WriteLine(weB.ToString());
        sR.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that after looping 256 times the RGB value turn 0 and does not change again for the rest if the pixel.
That is, it gives the correct RGB value for the image 256 times then everything turns 0.

This happen for any image of any color.

please what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The best way to write all pixel values to disk is via Bitmap.Save().

Comment: My boss wants it in a text file. Thanks

Comment: Is something else modifying image2 in another thread?

Comment: No, the problem is solved. I got an answer below. My constructor Was misplaced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbsak4dc(v=vs.110).aspx you should go with:

```
gr.DrawImage(image1,0,0,image2.Width,image2.Height);
```

not

```
gr.DrawImage(image1,0,0,image2.Height,image2.Width);
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. Problem solved